# cordova generated android app with socketio sends messages to server but can't receive messages

Tags: android, cordova, socket.io, client, vuetify.js

I have built a vue/vuetify app with a client server and a backend server with express rest API and socket API.

Client access express server on host:port both on socketio and with restapi and it work's fine.

Then I generated a Cordova native app for android and ios the looks very good.
All rest API works fine but when cordova client app sends socket messages to server that works great but the cordova client app doesn't receive the messages that the server sends to clients over socketio.

This works if the client app is used from webbrowser on android and ios.

So the cordova generated app has connections to the server and sends messages to the server over socketio. I have googled a lot and found one comment that android doesn't work as socket client if you don't implement it with a special activity. That sounds like a cordova bug for and not sure how to fix this in the cordova generated app. My  vue/vuetify javascript app is setting up evenlisteners that get server messages and updates client views. How to get this integrated with cordova native I don't know. Does anyone have any idea on how to trace and fix this? If I set up a socket io listener in the cordova native part how to integrate that with my generated script part of the app ?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say that i did a test and changed from Cordova to Capacitor and then my socketio channels to mobiles also worked. Also added Local Notifications and Push Notifications working very well on both Android and Iphone with Capacitor, Vue/Vuetify, Express, Sockets, Axios and a lot more.